# I can upvote/downvote some questions twice. Is it a bug?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting

I can upvote/downvote some questions(**not all**)([1st](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110404/proposed-improvement-to-flagging-for-answers), [2nd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109314/how-should-we-notify-people-that-theyre-eligible-for-microsoft-community-contr)) asked by [Joel Spolsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) two times; Is it okay? or bug?

**Initial vote (It was 120)**

> [image]

**I clicked once on upvote button,and the upvote button didn't changed its color to blue(Now the vote is 121)**

> [image]

**I again clicked (two times)Now the vote is 122**

> [image]

Comment: @Shadow Wizard -Stricltly not.. Did your head hitting somewhere?

Comment: You can't upvote twice. Suppose the question had score of 121 initially. The only possible explanation is that you first cast a downvote, so it became 120, then you clicked the upvote button which undid the downvote, making it back to 121 and added an upvote making it 122. So you saw it "jump" from 120 to 122. This is documented in the faq I linked to, hence duplicate. My head is fine, thanks.

Comment: Also, looking in the [question timeline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/110404/timeline), there is only one upvote today so no matter what, no "2 points increase".

Comment: I upvoted two times, I'm sure that this initially the point was 120, and when I clicked on upvote, it increased to 121 but the upvote icon didnt changed to blue color, and i waited for about 1 min, and refreshed, the point still remained in 121 and I again clicked in upvote button. Then now it goes again +1,(total now, 122).

Comment: No. Trust me, you do not have super powers. (even if you somehow could do it, it would have been documented in timeline, and would have given Joel +10 and not +5)

Comment: I will explain with screenshot, this may be a bug...

Comment: OK, no idea what's going on. Looks like a weird display bug, like I said, it did not have "real" effect but still, if that's what you see it is a bug.

Comment: At the same time if i'll click on downvote, it will down to -2, means 120... If you can't believe , i Can give you my account credentials.check yourself. no problem.

Comment: No thanks, I'm 99.999% sure that it's something on your end, e.g. slow connection or fancy browser extensions causing weird issues. Can you try different browser?

Comment: I tried to upvote but could do only once as which is intended. @ShadowWizard is right, there must some problem at your end.

Answer (score 13):

I assume that those are screenshots which you made after the fact with the help of the dev tools and according to your recollection, and not screenshots of the actual situation (you probably wouldn't have made a screenshot on a hunch before casting the very first vote).

Several points:

- The recorded votes on that post are entirely consistent. So whatever issues you may have seen would only be display issues on your end; there was no point in time at which there were two simultaneous active (i.e. non-retracted) votes from you.
- According to both the recorded votes and to the access logs, you clicked the vote arrows as follows: up, 4 seconds pause, down, 7 seconds, up, 2s, up, 3s, up, 1s, down, 4s, down. The time pauses are based on when the request was handled by our server. However your connection to our servers seems fairly flaky; those voting request had client request time values* varying between one and seven seconds. If nothing else this means that the times between you clicking a vote arrow and our server response saying "okay, vote registered" were both erratic and long. Combine that with clicking vote arrows repeatedly and in short succession, it doesn't seem improbable that the displayed vote count seems to behave strangely to you.
- Your recollection that the question's initial score was 120 is very likely wrong, because

  1. The correct score, according to all recorded votes, would indeed have been 121;
  2. while that value is denormalized and may in very rare cases be off if multiple people vote on the post at the same time, it is checked (and if necessary corrected) daily, and before today the last voting activity on that question was four months ago; and
  3. [Google's most recent cache entry of that question](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F110404%2Fproposed-improvement-to-flagging-for-answers&oq=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F110404%2Fproposed-improvement-to-flagging-for-answers&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j5l2j69i60l2.1527j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), at the time that I'm writing this, is from January 23rd (three weeks ago) and shows a score of 121.

---

<sub>*This is HAProxy's `Tq` control point, which is "the time elapsed between the moment the client connection was accepted
    and the moment the proxy received the last HTTP header"</sub>

Comment: No, when you click the downvote button the score should decrease by 2, that's absolutely correct. Currently, you have upvoted the question. So if you then click the down arrow, that does two things: Retract your upvote (-1) and cast a downvote (-1 again).

Comment: could you cancel my upvote for that mentioned questions, so that I can check again.

Comment: I agree with the assertion here. I have seen client side voting act strangely when the internet connection is either slow or dropping packets. On first click the page gives you the benefit of the doubt, but it can sometimes take a second to actually register the vote. Refreshing during these times will load a page which did not reflect the vote. A second refresh shows the vote present. However, I have never been able to get a +2 in, and also I do not see the question in the OP's example having 120 so that irregularity kind of detracts from the legitimacy here.

Answer (score 4):

If you *retract* your vote, then you can vote again. Which you did, and then did.

There are limits to this however: you have a 5-minute window in which you can change your vote. After that, your vote is locked-in until/unless the post is edited.

Comment: Can you please take a look in the edited question? Something weird is going on.